# Looping over rest of tab while creating object Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

Sorry for my title which is unclear, but I don't know how to say it differently.
I have an object "Rapport" which takes a couple of parameters (3 Strings and one Object). This Object "SortingParameter" takes a number of boolean arguments "boolean... args". My goal is to read lines in a text file, create an ArrayList made of these "Rapport" objects. For this, I loop through the lines:

```
for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("myTxt.txt"),Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))) {
    String[] split = line.split(";");
    if(split.length>3){
        rapports.add(new Rapport(split[0],split[1],split[2],new SortingParameter(PROBLEM)));
    }else{
        rapports.add(new Rapport(split[0],split[1],split[2]));
    }
```

**I would like to add the rest of my split[ ] tab in the object dynamically**. Does anybody know how this could be cleanly done?

The rest of my code:
Rapport.java

```
package model;

import static model.Constant.RESSOURCES;

public class Rapport {
    private String nomListe;
    private String nomRessource;
    private String categorie;
    private SortingParameter param;
    private boolean hasParameter;

    public Rapport(String nomListe, String nomRessource, String categorie, SortingParameter param){
        this.nomListe = nomListe;this.nomRessource = RESSOURCES + nomRessource; 
        this.categorie = categorie;this.param = param;
        this.hasParameter = true;
    }
    public Rapport(String nomListe, String nomRessource, String categorie){
        this.nomListe = nomListe; this.nomRessource = RESSOURCES + nomRessource;
        this.categorie = categorie; this.param = null; this.hasParameter = false;
    }

    /** Getters **/
    public String getNomListe(){return nomListe;}
    public String getNomRessource(){return nomRessource;}
    public String getCategorie(){return categorie;}
    public boolean hasParameter(){return hasParameter;}
    public SortingParameter getParam(){return param;}

}
```

And my SortingParameter.java:

```
package model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SortingParameter {
    private ArrayList<Boolean> paramList;

    public SortingParameter(boolean... args){
        paramList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (boolean arg : args) {
            paramList.add(arg);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Boolean> getParamList(){return paramList;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you want to add the rest of your split[]-tab to a Rapport-instance.
Just provide a String-Array as an attribute in your Rapport-class:

```
public class Rapport {
     //some attributes...
     private String[] eitherColumns;
     //getters and setters and so on....
}
```

Then, when you read a line from the file, use a setter or another constructor to add the rest of the tabs to your Rapport-Instance.

You can also use a separate constructor which only gets the String-Array read from the file and let the class decide what to do with the array-elements which would be more convenient so separate your business logic from your data.

Comment: You mean like an iterator? If more than 3 words, then the 3 words go into a tab and this tab is passed on to the new SortingParameter()?
I thought about this, I just wanted to know if there was an easier way, like a method which said: split[].REST(), and gave in the strings as litteral and not as a tab

Comment: So you would like to concat the tabs? If this is useful for you, you can do that - but it is always good to have access to the original data - you can make get another represantion by using different methods. I think i would give the complete String[]-array to the constructor and then set nomList, nomCategorie and nomRessource in the constructor. Then you create a new array without these 3 values where "new String[0]" is set to split[3] (and so on) and save this in eitherColumns. Then you can write a method getLiteratl() which returns one literal of eitherColumns as a String